# db2 luw - create db hitting error SQL1036C

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Please let me know what else need to investigate for this issue.

DB2 level: DB2 v 11.5.8
OS: Linux x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have created new instance with root and db2start successful with instance user: db2inst1.
db2ilist: output => db2inst1
Fenced user: db2fenc1
While trying to create database :test , hitting error message:
db2 create db test
SQL1036C An I/O error occurred while accessing the database. SQLSTATE=58030

I have verified /dev/shm permissions and granted 777
post that also getting same error message.
I have tried to drop instance and recreate the instance and then create db command but same issue exists.

In db2diag.log:

FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data protection services, sqlpgOpenGLFH, probe:120
MESSAGE: ZRC=0x90000001=-1879048191

DATA #1 : 
There was an error opening global LFH files:
/dbdata/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00001/SQLOGCTL.GLFH.1
/dbdata/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00001/SQLOGCTL.GLFH.2

one more entry in db2diag.log :
Level:Error

FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data protection services, sqpDoesMemberExistInCurDbTopology,probe:183
MESSAGE: ECF=0x90000001=-1879048191=ECF_ACCESS_DENIED
Access denied

Thanks.

Comment: Which distro and version of linux?  Study carefully the UID:GID for all of the directories in path /dbdata/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00001/  . It's unclear from your message which groups you've placed db2inst1 into, which what are the ownerships and permissions on those directories.

Comment: Thanks for reply. db2inst1 with db2iadm1 group and db2inst1 is owner for directory: /dbdata.
Path: /dbdata/db2inst1
db2fenc1 with group db2fadm1 and under directory: /dbdata/db2fenc1

Comment: issue resolved post fixed permission issues, thanks.